# When is the application of Kotlin infix functions appropriate?

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

The Kotlin language brings the simplification of function calls to the natural language. This [article](https://medium.com/makingtuenti/infix-functions-in-kotlin-2db3d3142dd2) shows a nice example:

- Function:

  ```kotlin
  fun of(suit: Suit) = Card(this, suit)
  ```

  ```kotlin
  val card = Rank.QUEEN.of(Suit.HEARTS)
  ```
- Infix function:

  ```kotlin
  infix fun of(suit: Suit) = Card(this, suit)
  ```

  ```kotlin
  val card = QUEEN of HEARTS
  ```

AS a newbie to Kotlin, I can imagine myself writing **every** function as an `infix` function, yet my intuition says it is wrong. There is endless supply of tutorials about how to write and use `infix` functions, but none of them explain the proper use cases.

Is there a rule of thumb on when it is appropriate to use an `infix` function and when not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`infix` should be treated like the syntactic sugar that it is: If it aids in the readability and flow of your code? Use it. Otherwise? Don't. That's really the only hard/fast rule. Mind that just b/c you *can* add `infix` doesn't mean you should. So while you *could*, through a series of complex higher order functions, generics, and callbacks, architect your code in a manner that allows you to write `dog bark at cat 4 times`, it's likely easier and more maintainable (and less burdensome on your compatriots) to write `dog.barkAt(cat, times=4)`

Personally, I find `infix` most useful when creating unit tests since I only really want to understand the gist of what's happening, and not the details.